# heroku rails logging not showing output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, logging, heroku

I am trying to debug an issue with one of my rails controllers. It works fine locally in development but pushing to heroku there is inconsistent behavior.

I have set `config.log_level = :debug` in `/app/config/production.rb`
I have tried addin `puts` and `logger.debug` statments to the controller.

I do see the output locally but am not seeing it on heroku. Per the heroku docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging This shouldn't be that hard.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `Rails.logger 'This is what I want to log'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set these config values to false to reload the code `app/config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.cache_classes = false                                                                                                                                                 
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```